# Tableview section expand collapsed updating after scroll

Tags: swift, tableview

I am facing issue that I am not able to solve

I have created sections on tap of it. I am reloading section in between begin update and endUpdate.

The problem is when I press button to expand the cell All cells are invisible until I scroll back

```
        self.tblCommentlist.beginUpdates()
        self.arrComments[cell.section].isExpanded =  !self.arrComments[cell.section].isExpanded

        self.tblCommentlist.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: cell.section), with: .fade)
        self.tblCommentlist.endUpdates()
```

[image]

But it is not working as expected.

Please help me to solve this

here is sample project. It is the same code shown in image
https://github.com/PrashantKT/ExpandableTableviewDemo/tree/master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strange !!

I found solution.

The issue was in this function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StoryBoard.Cells.CommentCell) as! CommentCell
   return cell
 }
```

I am returning the the cell object.

If I change  from

```
return cell
```

to

```
return cell.contentView
```

Every thing is working fine. All animation are perfectly running.

Hope helpful to someone facing same issue